# Convert UUID to String representation eg: 1816 to Cycling Speed And Cadence

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I'm connecting to a Cycling Speed and Cadence service via bluetooth and am saving the peripheral into an array (for tableview).

I have implemented this struct

```
struct BTPeripheral: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let uuid: UUID
    let desc: String
}
```

and am calling is as

```
discoveredBTDevices.append(BTPeripheral.init(
                           id: discoveredBTDevices.count, 
                           name: peripheral.name!, 
                           uuid: peripheral.identifier, 
                           desc: service.uuid.uuidstring) // trying service.uuid results in error
)
```

which results in this output

```
id: 0, 
name: "Wahoo CADENCE 1DE8", 
uuid: E98F3843-1C6A-E4DE-6EF3-76B013950007, 
desc: "1816"
```

The description is the string 1816 (which is the UUID of the cycle Speed & Cad service)

```
let serviceCyclingSpeedAndCadenceUUID             = CBUUID(string: "1816")
```

How can I convert the 1816 into the string "Cycling Speed and Cadence" which is what gets printed out

```
print(service.uuid) // this results in "cycling Speed and Cadence"
```

As noted above, putting `service.uuid` results in an error `Cannot convert value of type 'CBUUID' to expected argument type 'String'`

Comment: How did you know that "1816" is the UUID (description) for "Cycling Speed and Cadence Service"? Is there list somewhere?

Comment: Yes. There is a list in bluetooth.com

Comment: Ah, thank you! I think I have found it: https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just get its `description` (which, IIRC, is what `print` will do eventually, as `CBUUID` conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`):

```
service.uuid.description
```

Or use a string interpolation:

```
"\(service.uuid)"
```

`debugDescription` produces the same result too, but I wouldn't use this unless this is actually for debugging.

Comment: I tried \(service.uuid) but did not know that I needed to include the quotes as well. I also previously tried peripheral.description but that just gave me a long list of items.